# Mass-spring system linear equations: I don't get the last term, shouldn't it be $V=\frac{1}{2}k_3x_{\text{wall}}^2-2k_3x_{\text{wall}}x_2+k_3x_2^2$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring, linear-systems, coupled-oscillators

I don't understand the last term in setting up the linear system of equations for multiple mass-spring systems. It is about the last spring in the next example:

[image]

Source: https://math24.net/mass-spring-system.html

I understand the terms, but for the last spring the potential energy is

$$ V= \frac{1}{2} k_3 \Delta x^2 $$

Where I am confused about the $\Delta x$. Shouldn't this be just the length of the spring, in other words, the difference between the $x$ position of the wall and the $x_2$ position of the mass $m_2$?

$$ \Delta x = x_{\text{wall}} - x_2$$
Which means:
$$ V= \frac{1}{2} k_3 \Delta x^2 = \frac{1}{2} k_3 (x_{\text{wall}} - x_2)^2$$
$$ V=\frac{1}{2} k_3 (x_{\text{wall}}^2 -2x_{\text{wall}}x_2+ x_2^2)$$
$$ V=\frac{1}{2} k_3x_{\text{wall}}^2 -2k_3x_{\text{wall}}x_2+ k_3x_2^2$$

Which is completely different than $\frac{k_3x_2^2}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't this be just the length of the spring, in other words, the difference between the  position of the wall and the 2 position of the mass 2?

$\Delta x$ refers to the change in spring's length, not the absolute length. In problems like this, one usually assumes each block's coordinate to be equal to zero when in equilibrium. In such coordinate choice, the position of the block $m_2$ is equivalent to the change in $k_3$ spring's length. So, $\Delta x = x_2$.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the choice of coordinate and the assumption of not-deformed spring in the initial configuration. It seems to me that the coordinates $x_1$, $x_2$ used here are the displacement from the equilibrium position, $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 0$, for which the springs are not deformed.

With these coordinates, the change of length of the springs reads

$\Delta \ell_1 = x_1 \quad$,$ \quad$
$\Delta \ell_2 = x_2-x_1 \quad$,$ \quad$
$\Delta \ell_3 = -x_2$

and the potential energy reads

$V_1 = \dfrac{1}{2} k_1 \Delta \ell_1^2 = \dfrac{1}{2} k_1 x_1^2 \quad$,$\quad$
$V_2 = \dfrac{1}{2} k_2 \Delta \ell_2^2 = \dfrac{1}{2} k_2 (x_2 - x_1)^2 \quad,\quad$
$V_3 = \dfrac{1}{2} k_3 \Delta \ell_3^2 = \dfrac{1}{2} k_2 x_2^2 $

Answer (score 0):

There is a different coordinate system for each of the masses as shown below.

[image]

$x_1=0$ is the equilibrium position for mass $m_1$ and $x_1$ represents the displacement of mass $m_1$ from the equilibrium position.

$x_2=0$ is the equilibrium position for mass $m_2$ and $x_2$ represents the displacement of mass $m_2$ from the equilibrium position.

Thus for mass $m_2$ if the spring $k_3$ is relaxed when $x_2=0$, then when the mass $m_2$ is displaced $x_2$ the length of spring $k_3$ has changed by $x_2$.
The energy stored in spring $k_3$ is then $\frac 12 k_3 x_2^2$.